# How to generate mock automatically in google mock for c

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googlemock

I know there is a tool called gmock_gen.py in google mock that can be used to automatically generate mocks for c++ classes. Is there any similar tool that can generate mock for c functions, given a c source file, in which I want to mock those functions?

The background for my question:

I have lots of legacy c code (not c++) that need to be unit tested by google test and google mock. To test a function, I have to mock hundreds of functions that are called by some functions in the same c source file, even though they are not called by the function under unit test, otherwise, there will be "undefined reference" problems when linking.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could take a look at this  github repo : https://github.com/hjagodzinski/C-Mock

From the doc :

`C Mock is Google Mock extension allowing for mocking functions.`

`This is not either a patch to nor fork of Google Mock. This is just a set of headers providing a way of using tools for mock methods with mock functions in tests.`

`C Mock is not intended to promote bad design. Its goal is to help people test their code.`

Comment: Thank you, Nicolas. I can use this tool to mock only those functions that I need to, leaving other irrelevant functions unchanged. But it needs to define a mock object before calling mock function. It's infeasible for my situation, since all my codes are legacy code in c. I can't modify the code to add such a mock object. Also, the c compiler may not understand c++ classes and objects.

Comment: Also, if I do need to mock a lot of functions, I still have to add this mock function manually. So, it would be better if there is an automatic mock generator for c functions.